# What's the meaning of the "rather as though" in this example?

Tags: meaning, idioms

As I was reading on the Internet, I came across this:

> Even if they want to have it, they can't. It is **rather as though**, over an immense range of intellectual experience, a whole group was tone-deaf.

I was wondering what's the meaning of "rather as though" (in bold) in this phrase.

Comment: The comma is incorrect. "It is rather as though over an immense range of intellectual experience, a whole group was tone-deaf." means "A fair comparison would be a whole group, over an immense range of intellectual experience, being tone-deaf."

Comment: Short story: you can replace *rather as though* with *as if*.

Comment: Thanks Edwin for the correction, I've edited it. And thanks as well to Dan, now I understand the meaning of this. Thanks to you two for your quick replies.

Comment: @DanBron: More precisely, you can replace *as though* by *as if*, and *rather* as *quite*, *somewhat*, *a bit*, or *to some extent*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "rather" is misplaced, here. "Rather" is usually used to offer an alternative to something mentioned earlier. Instead, the second sentence is just clarifying the first. It should be "It is **as though**, over an immmense...".

"Rather" has another meaning, however, which is something like "more than expected/usual". For example, "He is rather opinionated" would mean that he is more opinionated than the speaker is accustomed to. So, in that context, it *could* be that the author meant that it was *more* as though the group was tone-deaf than would be expected. However, that sounds strange, too.

Comment: Thanks for this precision, I'll remember that. It looks rather and plutôt that we use in French are quite similar.